# Converting Date value from GridView and putting it in a TextBox in correct format

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to take a Date value from a GridView in Windows Forms and putting it in the correct format in a text TextBox. A MySQL database has this field as Date, so it displays a weird 12:00:00 AM behind the Date, which does not show in the GridView but it does in the TextBox.

Here is the Code I am using to transport the Date from the GridView into the TextBox:

```
if (jobCardGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    submitedBy_tb.Text = jobCardGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Submited By"].Value.ToString();
    date_tb.Text = jobCardGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Date"].Value.ToString();
    nextService_tb.Text = jobCardGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Next Service"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Say the GridView displays `23 11 2016`, the TextBox will display `23 11 2016 12:00:00 AM`, to my inconvenience, as I'm trying to display the Date in a `DD/MM/YY` format.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have applied a format to the cell, you can use:

```
jobCardGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Next Service"].FormattedValue().ToString();
```

If the .Value property it's a DateTime, can cast it and then format the final result:

```
DateTime t = (DateTime)jobCardGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Next Service"].Value;
nextService_tb.Text = t.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Comment: The second Option Worked Perfectly Thanks For The Quick Reply :)